# how we remove index in the array and merge

Tags: php, arrays

**Bellow is my Array in this array**
****i want to remove second level index 1 and 2 and merge two arrays in one array****

```
$array1 = Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2] => 4
                    [3] => 2
                    [4] => 3
                    [5] => 

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [9] => 4
                    [10] => 
                    [11] => 4
                    [12] => 4

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 4.1428571428571
                    [5] => 5

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [9] => 3
                    [10] => 5
                    [11] => 5
                    [12] => 3

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [2] => 5
                    [3] => 5
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 4.1428571428571

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [9] => 3
                    [10] => 4.4285714285714
                    [11] => 4.4285714285714
                    [12] => 5

                )

        )
```

**my aspected output is bellow where second level index is removed and arrays are merged**

```
$array1= Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
                    [2] => 4
                    [3] => 2
                    [4] => 3
                    [5] => 
                    [9] => 4
                    [10] => 
                    [11] => 4
                    [12] => 4



        )

    [2] => Array
        (
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 
                    [4] => 4.1428571428571
                    [5] => 5
                    [9] => 3
                    [10] => 5
                    [11] => 5
                    [12] => 3

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (

                    [2] => 5
                    [3] => 5
                    [4] => 
                    [5] => 4.1428571428571
                    [9] => 3
                    [10] => 4.4285714285714
                    [11] => 4.4285714285714
                    [12] => 5

               )
```

And i tried :

```
foreach($array1 as $arrkey => $arrvalue)
        {
            foreach($arrvalue as $innerkey => $innervalue){
                //unset($cutvalu[$cutck]);
                foreach($innervalue as $subkey => $subvalue){
                    @$array1[$arrkey][$subkey];

                }
            }
        }

     echo "<pre>"; print_r($array1);echo "<pre>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($array1 as $arrkey => $arrvalue)
    {
        foreach($arrvalue as $innerkey => $innervalue){

           foreach($innervalue as $subkey => $subvalue){

                $new_array[$arrkey][$subkey] = $subvalue; // Change this line

            }
        }
    }

 echo "<pre>"; print_r($new_array);echo "<pre>";
```

This will give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Sir really thanku so much my problem is solved really thankx stay bless